# Bind enum to telerik column in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, enums

I've found the example at telerik forum of binding enum to radgridview, but it doesn't work hwo I need, and I need it on today, so i need a help.

Below are classes of this example, and only difference which I need is possibility to change value of positionof players. Now I can only change position by typing new value, but I need to select it from comboboxcolumn.

How can I do it?

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingGridViewToEnumCollection.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:my="clr-namespace:BindingGridViewToEnumCollection"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="700">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <my:MyViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
          Background="White" 
          DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <telerik:RadGridView Name="playersGrid" Grid.Row="0"
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Players}" 
                                     AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Number}"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Position}"/>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Country}"/>
            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        </telerik:RadGridView>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BindingGridViewToEnumCollection
{
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<Club> clubs;
        private ObservableCollection<Player> players;
        private object selectedItem;        


        //public IEnumerable<string> AssignedPositions
        public IEnumerable<Position> AssignedPositions
        {
            get
            {

                return new[] { Position.DF, Position.FW };

            }

        }


        public ObservableCollection<Club> Clubs
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.clubs == null)
                {
                    this.clubs = Club.GetClubs();
                }

                return this.clubs;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Player> Players
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.players == null)
                {
                    this.players = Player.GetPlayers();
                }

                return this.players;
            }
        }

        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get 
            { 
                return this.selectedItem; 
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.selectedItem)
                {
                    this.selectedItem = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, args);
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }


    }
}
```

Class Club:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace BindingGridViewToEnumCollection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A football club.
    /// </summary>
    public class Club : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string name;
        private DateTime established;
        private int stadiumCapacity;
        private ObservableCollection<Player> players;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.name)
                {
                    this.name = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        public DateTime Established
        {
            get { return this.established; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.established)
                {
                    this.established = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Established");
                }
            }
        }

        public int StadiumCapacity
        {
            get { return this.stadiumCapacity; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.stadiumCapacity)
                {
                    this.stadiumCapacity = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("StadiumCapacity");
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Player> Players
        {
            get
            {
                if (null == this.players)
                {
                    this.players = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
                }

                return this.players;
            }
        }

        public Club()
        {

        }

        public Club(string name, DateTime established, int stadiumCapacity)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.established = established;
            this.stadiumCapacity = stadiumCapacity;
        }

        public Club(string name, DateTime established, int stadiumCapacity, ObservableCollection<Player> players)
            : this(name, established, stadiumCapacity)
        {
            this.players = players;
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, args);
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<Club> GetClubs()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Club> clubs = new ObservableCollection<Club>();
            Club club;

            // Liverpool
            club = new Club("Liverpool", new DateTime(1892, 1, 1), 45362);
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Pepe Reina", 25, Position.GK, "Spain"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Jamie Carragher", 23, Position.DF, "England"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Steven Gerrard", 8, Position.MF, "England"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Fernando Torres", 9, Position.FW, "Spain"));
            clubs.Add(club);

            // Manchester Utd.
            club = new Club("Manchester Utd.", new DateTime(1878, 1, 1), 76212);
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Edwin van der Sar", 1, Position.GK, "Netherlands"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Rio Ferdinand", 5, Position.DF, "England"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Ryan Giggs", 11, Position.MF, "Wales"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Wayne Rooney", 10, Position.FW, "England"));
            clubs.Add(club);

            // Chelsea
            club = new Club("Chelsea", new DateTime(1905, 1, 1), 42055);
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Petr Čech", 1, Position.GK, "Czech Republic"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("John Terry", 26, Position.DF, "England"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Frank Lampard", 8, Position.MF, "England"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Nicolas Anelka", 39, Position.FW, "France"));
            clubs.Add(club);

            // Arsenal
            club = new Club("Arsenal", new DateTime(1886, 1, 1), 60355);
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Manuel Almunia", 1, Position.GK, "Spain"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Gaël Clichy", 22, Position.DF, "France"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Cesc Fàbregas", 4, Position.MF, "Spain"));
            club.Players.Add(new Player("Robin van Persie", 11, Position.FW, "Netherlands"));
            clubs.Add(club);

            return clubs;
        }
    }
}
```

class Player

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace BindingGridViewToEnumCollection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A football player.
    /// </summary>
    public class Player : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string name;
        private int number;
        private Position position;
        private string country;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.name)
                {
                    this.name = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        public int Number
        {
            get { return this.number; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.number)
                {
                    this.number = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Number");
                }
            }
        }

        public Position Position
        {
            get { return this.position; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.position)
                {
                    this.position = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Position");
                }
            }
        }

        public string Country
        {
            get { return this.country; }
            set
            {
                if (value != this.country)
                {
                    this.country = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Country");
                }
            }
        }

        public Player()
        {

        }

        public Player(string name, int number, Position position, string country)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
            this.position = position;
            this.country = country;
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, args);
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name;
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<Player> GetPlayers()
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Player>(Club.GetClubs().SelectMany(c => c.Players));
        }
    }
}

namespace BindingGridViewToEnumCollection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A football position.
    /// </summary>
    public enum Position
    {
        GK,
        DF,
        MF,
        FW
    }
}
```

EDIT

I'm using 2010.1.603.1040 version telerik, so I can't do i tlike there
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#GridView/EnumDataSource

Answer (score 1):

Your `DataMemberBinding` is wrong. You should add the mode:

DataMemberBinding="{Binding Position,**Mode=TwoWay**}"

```
<telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Position,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}">
    <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to add the following field and property to your `MyViewModel` class:

```
    private static readonly Position[] positions = new Position[]
    {
        Position.GK, Position.DF, Position.MF, Position.FW
    };

    public IEnumerable<Position> Positions
    {
        get { return positions; }
    }
```

(There's no [Enum.GetValues()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) in Silverlight, so we have to make our own collection of the enum's values.)

Then you can change the Position column of your RadGridView to the following:

```
            <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Position}"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}">
                <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Position}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
```

All we really should need to get the combobox column working is to change the type of the column to `GridViewComboBoxColumn` and add an `ItemsSource` that specifies the items to show in the combobox.  However, I found that the Position column had a habit of going blank when other columns were focused.  Once I added the CellTemplate. I found that the Position column behaved itself a bit better.

Note that you will need to set the `Mode` of your bindings to `TwoWay` if you want the changes you make in the grid to be sent back to your view-model.

Comment: Unfortunately everytime I try to select value from combobox this column lost value, and combobox is empty. But thanks for try